# "Create Unit Test" context menu option missing in Visual Studio 2017 (for VB.NET only)

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, mstest

I created a solution with following projects:

- A web application (asp.net) using C#
- A web application (asp.net) using VB.NET
- A unit test application using C# (tried with VB.NET also).

The "Create Unit Test" context menu option is missing in Visual Studio 2017 for VB.NET but is available for C#.

Does anyone know what I'm missing. Do I need to do anything special to get that option in projects using VB.NET language?

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2017.

**C# context menu**
[image]

**VB.NET context menu**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option was removed for VB.Net in an earlier release of Visual Studio (VS2015, or earlier) even though the option had been there (I remember using it in VS2018, for sure)